# How to get the occurrence of a tag in XSLT with its count increment over its occurrence

Tags: xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lines>
    <accounts>
        <account>
            <p lang="en">
                <trans> SAVINGS.</trans>
            </p>
        </account>
        <account>
            <p lang="en">
                <trans> CREDIT</trans>
            </p>
        </account>
    </accounts>
    <deposits>
        <account>
            <p lang="en">
                <trans> SAVINGS DEPOSIT.</trans>
            </p>
        </account>
        <account>
            <p lang="en">
                <trans> CREDIT DEPOSIT</trans>
            </p>
        </account>
    </deposits>
</lines>
```

But I want to print as below in XSLT:

```
Account 1) SAVINGS
Account 2) CREDIT
Account 3) SAVINGS DEPOSIT
Account 4) CREDIT DEPOSIT<
```

what XSLT expression will be best for this?

I tried with below XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="trans" >
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::account">
           Account <xsl:number value="count(account)" format="1"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I get the output as

```
Account 0 SAVINGS
Account 0 CREDIT   
Account 0 SAVINGS DEPOSIT             
Account 0 CREDIT DEPOSIT
```

what would be the best expression to resolve this..?

Comment: Post tried XSLT too...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xsl:template match="account//trans">
Account <xsl:number level="any" format="1)"/> <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWRApb

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/lines">
    <xsl:for-each select="*/account">
        <xsl:text>Account </xsl:text>
        <xsl:number value="position()" format="1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="p/trans"/>        
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```